# Share Telnet connection as a proxy

Tags: proxy, putty, telnet, tunneling, socks

i have telnet connection to device  behind firewall
(there is no SSH)
and  i want to  use  this connection as a proxy to  give local  network access to  Firefox for example
if is possible using Putty
thanks

Comment: What kind of a device are you connecting to? Is it a grown-up computer where you can run arbitrary software, or something embedded, like a network switch or a smart thermostat?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using `putty`. There have been some efforts trying to do ppp over telnet, but all that I've seen have abandoned this clumsy hack.

It surprises me that someone would give telnet access to a device behind a firewall.